# Create a connection to Office 365 using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, office365

I am trying to get distribution groups and users from Office 365 from a Visual WebPart solution in VS 2010. My question is how can I create a connection to Office 365 using C#?

Comment: It looks like Office 365 works with VS 2012 and later

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at the Office365 REST API. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview) is one suggestion on where to start.